# merge rows in a sql query and create additional columns for different information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query that is returning a number of customer results.

each customer has a unique ID but may have multiple transactions.

instead of having multiple rows for each customer i would like to have one row and generate multiple columns for the different info.

for example i have:

```
id    | name |  purchase price |  date
3     | tim  |    20           | 08-2-2014
3     | tim  |    25           | 08-5-2014
```

and i want it to read

```
id    | name |  purchase price 1 |  date 1    |  purchase price 2 |  date 2
3     | tim  |      20           | 08-2-2014  |      25           | 08-5-2014
```

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Google either dynamic PIVOT or dynamic cross tab. Either approach will work for this.

Comment: 1st try google search "Dynamic Pivot SQL Server" plenty of stuff available there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using a dynamic cross tab. 
For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
-- build sample data
create table #temp_table(
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    [purchase price] decimal(10,2),
    [date] smalldatetime
)

insert into #temp_table
select 3, 'tim', 20, '20140802' union all
select 3, 'tim', 25, '20140805' union all
select 4, 'joe', 25, '20140801' union all
select 4, 'joe', 25, '20140803' union all
select 4, 'joe', 25, '20140807' union all
select 1, 'bob', 25, '20140811'

declare @sql1 varchar(4000)
declare @sql2 varchar(4000)
declare @sql3 varchar(4000)

declare @max int
declare @counter int


select @counter = 1
select top 1 @max =  count(*) from #temp_table group by id order by count(*) desc-- get number of columns

select @sql1 =
'select 
    id, 
    name,
'

select @sql3 = 
'from(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by id, name order by [date])
    from #temp_table
)t
group by id, name
order by id'

select @sql2 = ''
while @counter <= @max begin
    select @sql2 = 
        @sql2
        + ' max(case when rn = ' + convert(varchar(10),@counter) + ' then [purchase price] else null end) as [purchase price ' + convert(varchar(10),@counter) + '],' + char(10)
        + ' max(case when rn = ' + convert(varchar(10),@counter) + ' then [date] else null end) as [date ' + convert(varchar(10),@counter) + ']'

    if @counter <> @max begin
        select @sql2 = @sql2 + ','
    end
    select @sql2 = @sql2 + char(10)
    select @counter = @counter + 1
end


print (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
exec (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)


drop table #temp_table
```

Sample Data:

```
id  name   purchase price    date
----------------------------------------
3   tim    20.00             2014-08-02 00:00:00
3   tim    25.00             2014-08-05 00:00:00
4   joe    25.00             2014-08-01 00:00:00
4   joe    25.00             2014-08-03 00:00:00
4   joe    25.00             2014-08-07 00:00:00
1   bob    25.00             2014-08-11 00:00:00
```

Result:

```
id  name    purchase price 1    date 1                  purchase price 2    date 2                  purchase price 3    date 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   bob     25.00               2014-08-11 00:00:00     NULL                NULL                    NULL                NULL
3   tim     20.00               2014-08-02 00:00:00     25.00               2014-08-05 00:00:00     NULL                NULL
4   joe     25.00               2014-08-01 00:00:00     25.00               2014-08-03 00:00:00     25.00               2014-08-07 00:00:00
```